# Detecting object collision with spatial partitioning in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to create a system of many objects that preform an action when they collide with each other, I'm using the P5.min.js library.

I've set up an array for the grid and an array for the objects, but I can't figure out the right way to go through each grid cell and check only the objects inside that cell before moving on to the next cell.

Here's what I've got so far

```
let molecules = [];
const numOfMolecules = 100;
let collisions = 0;
let check = 0;
let maxR = 10; //max molecule radius
let minR = 2; //min molecule radius
let numOfCol = 5;
let numOfRow = 5;
let CellW = 600/numOfCol; //gridWidth
let CellH = 600/numOfRow; //gridHeight
let remain = numOfMolecules;
let gridArray = [];



function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    background(127);

    for (let i = 0; i < numOfMolecules; i++) {
        molecules.push(new Molecule());
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(127);

    molecules.forEach(molecule => {
        molecule.render();
        molecule.checkEdges();
        molecule.step();
    });

    drawGrid();
    splitIntoGrid();
    collision();
    displayFR();
}

function drawGrid() {
    for (i = 0; i < numOfRow+1; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < numOfCol+1; j++){
            noFill();
            stroke(0);
            rect(CellW*(j-1), CellH*(i-1), CellW, CellH);
        }
    }
}

function splitIntoGrid(){
    for (let i = 0; i < numOfRow; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < numOfCol; j++){
            tempArray = [];
            molecules.forEach(molecule => {
                if (molecule.position.x > (CellW*j) &&
                    molecule.position.x < (CellW*(j+1)) &&
                    molecule.position.y > (CellH*i) &&
                    molecule.position.y < (CellH*(i+1))) {
                        tempArray.push(molecule.id);
                    }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

How I'm checking collision between all objects:

```
function collision() {
    for (let i=0; i < molecules.length; i++){
        for (let j=0; j < molecules.length; j++){
            let diff = p5.Vector.sub(molecules[j].position, molecules[i].position);
            check++;
            if (i != j && diff.mag() <= molecules[j].radius + molecules[i].radius){
                collisions++;
                molecules[j].changeColor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, I need to put these for loops inside another one going through each cell in the grid, but I don't know how to limit the search to which ever tempArray(s) the object is in

If this makes any sense, this is what I'm trying to do

```
function collision() {
  for (let k = 0; k < gridArray.length; k++){
    for (let i=0; i < gridArray.tempArray.length; i++){
        for (let j=0; j < gridArray.tempArray.length; j++){
            let diff = p5.Vector.sub(gridArray.tempArray[j].position, gridArray.tempArray.position);
            check++;
            if (i != j && diff.mag() <= gridArray.tempArray[j].radius + gridArray.tempArray[i].radius){
                collisions++;
                gridArray.tempArray[j].changeColor();
                gridArray.tempArray[i].changeColor();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grid cell is represented by an array of array `gridArray`. You need to have a collection of molecules *for each* grid cell.  My recommendation would be to use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)s instead of an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) since the order is irrelevant. The idea is to be able to access the set of molecules on a given grid cell `(i,j)` with the syntax:

```
gridArray[i][j]
```

The following code will create an array of *`numOfRow`* arrays:

```js
const numOfRow = 5;

const gridArray = (new Array(numOfRow)).fill([]);
```

`gridArray` with look like this:

```
[ [], [], [], [], [] ]
```

Inside `splitIntoGrid` you are checking which molecules are in which grid cells. This is good. However, for each grid cell, you are overwriting the *global* variable `tempArray`. Therefore, at the end of the function's execution, `tempArray` will only hold the molecules of the last grid cell, which isn't what you want. For a given grid cell, we will add the right molecules to a `Set` associated with this grid cell.

The `Set` data structure has an [`#add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) method which appends a new element to the set:

```js
function splitIntoGrid() {
    for (let i = 0; i < numOfRow; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < numOfCol; j++) {
            gridArray[i][j] = new Set();
            molecules.forEach(molecule => {
                if (molecule.position.x > (CellW*j) 
                    && molecule.position.x < (CellW*(j+1))
                    && molecule.position.y > (CellH*i) 
                    && molecule.position.y < (CellH*(i+1))) {
                        gridArray[i][j].add(molecule);
                    }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now you're ready to check for collisions on each grid cells. We will have a total of four loops inside one another. Two to navigate through the grid and two to compare the molecules that are contained inside each grid cell:

```js
function collision() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numOfRow; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numOfCol; j++) {
      gridArray[i][j].forEach(moleculeA => {
        gridArray[i][j].forEach(moleculeB => {
          const diff = p5.Vector.sub(moleculeA.position, moleculeB.position);
          if (moleculeA != moleculeB && diff.mag() <= moleculeA.radius + moleculeB.radius) {
            collisions++;
            moleculeA.changeColor();
            moleculeB.changeColor();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code, [`#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) comes in handy.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I wasn't familiar with sets. I've changed the things you went over, and all the functions work perfectly except for collision, do I need to declare and update moleculeA and moleculeB somewhere? When I run with collision, I get this error: https://imgur.com/a/YnuaIOz

Comment: @Marcus, could you add a `console.log(i,j)` just before the `const diff` line and tell me what logs in the console? That will help know if `gridArray` is the issue here. Printing `moleculeA.position` and `moleculeB.position` would help too. NB: both are available because you're are looping through `gridArray` (which is a 2D array).

Comment: The problem is happening right on the first grid cell `gridArray[0][0]`. Could you comment out the two `gridArray[i][j]` `forEach` loops and add `gridArray[i][j].forEach(console.log)`? Like this: `function collision() { for (let i = 0; i < numOfRow; i++) { for (let j = 0; j < numOfCol; j++) { gridArray[i][j].forEach(console.log) } } }`. Also you might want to check if your molecules have a `position` property. (@Marcus)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, it seems to be going through the array without problems, and the position is saved for each molecule https://imgur.com/a/JqrczKR

Comment: I still have the problem when the girdArray[i][j] forEach loops aren't commented out

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't realise you had the loops commented out on this log. I just noticed I was adding the molecules' `id` and not the whole object to the sets (inside `splitIntoGrid`). Replace `gridArray[i][j].add(molecule.id)` with `gridArray[i][j].add(molecule)` and it should work fine!